# Sphinx internal error/ query not send to searchd

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx with a service called questasy (nobody will know it). Our dutch colleges did this before and the software is definitely giving us the opportunity to run searches via Sphinx.

So here the problem I got:

- I set up the questasy portal, enabled the questasy usage and the portal runs perfectly.
- I unpacked Sphinx to C:/Sphinx, created the `/data` and `/log` directories.
- I set up the config file and ran the indexer. It works.
- I installed `searchd` as a service with the config and it works and runs.

BUT now when I try to search in the portal it shows me a message like "internal error. Please try again later". When I look into the "Query.log" there is nothing in it, so I think the query isn't send to the searchd-service. I checked the config, I checked the port it is listening on and everything is like our colleges got it too.

Does anybody know about a common bug or problem or something like this we missed??

Here is my `.conf`:

```
# Questasy configuration file for sphinx
#
# To handle the Sphinx requirement that every document have a unique 32-bit ID,
# use a unique number for each index as the first 8 bits, and then use
# the normal index from the database for the last 24 bits.
# Here is the list of "index ids"
# 1 - English Question Text
# 2 - Dutch Question Text
# 3 - Concepts
# 4 - Variables
# 5 - Study Units
# 6 - Publications
#
# The full index will combine all of these indexes
#
# COMMANDS
# To index all of the files (when searchd is not running), use the command:
# indexer.exe --config qbase.conf --all
# To index all of the files (when searchd is running), use the command:
# indexer.exe --config qbase.conf --all --rotate
# Set up searchd as a service with the command
# searchd.exe --install --config c:\full\path\to\qbase.conf
# Stop searchd service with the command
# searchd.exe --stop --config c:\full\path\to\qbase.conf
# Remove searchd service with the command
# searchd.exe --delete --config c:\full\path\to\qbase.conf
# To just run searchd for development/testing
# searchd.exe --config qbase.conf

# base class with basic connection information
source base_source
{
    type                    = mysql

    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = root
    sql_pass                = 
    sql_db                  = questasy
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
}

# Query for English Question Text
source questions_english : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((1<<24)|QuestionItem.id) as id, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id, QuestionItem.lh_text_1 as question_text, GROUP_CONCAT(Code.lt_label_1 SEPARATOR ' ') as answer_text FROM `question_items` AS `QuestionItem` LEFT JOIN `question_schemes` AS `QuestionScheme` ON (`QuestionItem`.`question_scheme_id` = `QuestionScheme`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `data_collections` AS `DataCollection` ON (`DataCollection`.`id` = `QuestionScheme`.`data_collection_id`) LEFT JOIN `study_units` AS `StudyUnit` ON (`StudyUnit`.`id` = `DataCollection`.`study_unit_id`) LEFT JOIN `response_domains` AS `ResponseDomain` ON (`QuestionItem`.`response_domain_id` = `ResponseDomain`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `code_schemes` As `CodeScheme` ON (`ResponseDomain`.`code_scheme_id` = `CodeScheme`.`id` AND `ResponseDomain`.`domain_type`=4) LEFT JOIN `codes` AS `Code` ON (`Code`.`code_scheme_id` = `CodeScheme`.`id`) WHERE `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 20 GROUP BY QuestionItem.id

    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/question_items/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Dutch Question Text
source questions_dutch : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((2<<24)|QuestionItem.id) as id, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id, QuestionItem.lh_text_2 as question_text, GROUP_CONCAT(Code.lt_label_2 SEPARATOR ' ') as answer_text FROM `question_items` AS `QuestionItem` LEFT JOIN `question_schemes` AS `QuestionScheme` ON (`QuestionItem`.`question_scheme_id` = `QuestionScheme`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `data_collections` AS `DataCollection` ON (`DataCollection`.`id` = `QuestionScheme`.`data_collection_id`) LEFT JOIN `study_units` AS `StudyUnit` ON (`StudyUnit`.`id` = `DataCollection`.`study_unit_id`) LEFT JOIN `response_domains` AS `ResponseDomain` ON (`QuestionItem`.`response_domain_id` = `ResponseDomain`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `code_schemes` As `CodeScheme` ON (`ResponseDomain`.`code_scheme_id` = `CodeScheme`.`id` AND `ResponseDomain`.`domain_type`=4) LEFT JOIN `codes` AS `Code` ON (`Code`.`code_scheme_id` = `CodeScheme`.`id`) WHERE `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 20 GROUP BY QuestionItem.id

    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/question_items/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Concepts
source concepts : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((3<<24)|Concept.id) as id, Concept.lt_label_1 as concept_label, Concept.lh_description_1 as concept_description FROM `concepts` AS `Concept`

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/concepts/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Data Variable
source variables : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((4<<24)|DataVariable.id) as id, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id, DataVariable.name as variable_name, DataVariable.lh_label_1 as variable_label FROM `data_variables` AS `DataVariable` LEFT JOIN `variable_schemes` AS `VariableScheme` ON (`DataVariable`.`variable_scheme_id` = `VariableScheme`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `base_logical_products` AS `BaseLogicalProduct` ON (`BaseLogicalProduct`.`id` = `VariableScheme`.`base_logical_product_id`) LEFT JOIN `study_units` AS `StudyUnit` ON (`StudyUnit`.`id` = `BaseLogicalProduct`.`study_unit_id`) WHERE `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 15

    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/data_variables/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Study Units
source study_units : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((5<<24)|StudyUnit.id) as id, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id, StudyUnit.fulltitle as study_unit_name, StudyUnit.subtitle as study_unit_subtitle, StudyUnit.alternate_title AS study_unit_alternatetitle, StudyUnit.lh_note_1 as study_unit_note, StudyUnit.lh_purpose_1 as study_unit_purpose, StudyUnit.lh_abstract_1 as study_unit_abstract, StudyUnit.creator as study_unit_creator FROM study_units AS StudyUnit WHERE `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 10

    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/study_units/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Publications
source publications : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((6<<24)|Publication.id) as id, Publication.id as publication_id, Publication.title as publication_name, Publication.subtitle as publication_subtitle, Publication.creator as publication_creator, Publication.contributor as publication_contributor, Publication.abstract as publication_abstract, Publication.lh_note_1 as publication_note, Publication.source as publication_source FROM publications AS Publication WHERE NOT(`Publication`.`accepted_timestamp` IS NULL)

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/publications/view/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Hosted Files - Other materials
source other_materials : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((7<<24)|HostedFile.id) as id, OtherMaterial.title as hosted_file_title, HostedFile.name as hosted_file_name, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id FROM `hosted_files` as `HostedFile`, `other_materials` as OtherMaterial, `study_units` as `StudyUnit` WHERE OtherMaterial.hosted_file_id = HostedFile.id AND OtherMaterial.study_unit_id = StudyUnit.id AND `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 20
    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id

#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/hosted_files/download/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Hosted Files - Datasets
source physical_instances : base_source
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((8<<24)|HostedFile.id) as id, PhysicalInstance.name as hosted_file_name, StudyUnit.id as study_unit_id FROM `hosted_files` as `HostedFile`, `physical_instances` as PhysicalInstance, `study_units` as `StudyUnit` WHERE PhysicalInstance.hosted_file_id = HostedFile.id AND PhysicalInstance.study_unit_id = StudyUnit.id AND `StudyUnit`.`published` >= 20

    sql_attr_uint           = study_unit_id
#   sql_query_info      = SELECT CONCAT('/hosted_files/download/',$id) AS URL
}

# Query for Physical Data Products (Variable Schemes)
source physical_data_products : base_source 
{
    sql_query               = SELECT ((9<<24)| PhysicalDataProduct.id) as id, PhysicalDataProduct.name FROM `physical_data_products` AS `PhysicalDataProduct`, `study_units` as `StudyUnit` WHERE PhysicalDataProduct.study_unit_id = StudyUnit.id AND PhysicalDataProduct.deleted = 0 AND StudyUnit.published >= 20

}

# English Question Text Index
index questions_english_index
{
    source          = questions_english
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\questions_english_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Dutch Question Text Index
index questions_dutch_index
{
    source          = questions_dutch
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\questions_dutch_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Concept Index
index concepts_index
{
    source          = concepts
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\concepts_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Variable Index
index variables_index
{
    source          = variables
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\variables_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Study Unit Index
index study_units_index
{
    source          = study_units
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\study_units_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Publication Index
index publications_index
{
    source          = publications
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\publications_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Other Materials Index
index other_materials_index
{
    source          = other_materials
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\other_materials_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Datasets file Index
index physical_instances_index
{
    source          = physical_instances
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\physical_instances_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Datasets Index
index physical_data_products_index
{
    source          = physical_data_products
    path            = C:\Sphinx\data\physical_data_products_index
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
#   enable_star     = 1
    html_strip      = 1
#   charset_type        = utf-8
}

# Full Index - merge all of the other indexes
index full_index
{
    type            = distributed

    local           = questions_english_index
    local           = questions_dutch_index
    local           = concepts_index
    local           = variables_index
    local           = study_units_index
    local           = publications_index
    local           = other_materials_index
    local           = physical_instances_index
    local           = physical_data_products_index
}

indexer
{
    # memory limit, in bytes, kiloytes (16384K) or megabytes (256M)
    # optional, default is 32M, max is 2047M, recommended is 256M to 1024M
    mem_limit           = 256M

    # maximum IO calls per second (for I/O throttling)
    # optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
    #
    # max_iops          = 40


    # maximum IO call size, bytes (for I/O throttling)
    # optional, default is 0 (unlimited)
    #
    # max_iosize        = 1048576
}

# Settings for the searchd service
searchd
{
#   port                = 3312
    log             = C:\Sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log           = C:\Sphinx\log\query.log
    pid_file            = C:\Sphinx\log\searchd.pid
    listen          = 127.0.0.1
}

    # C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --config      C:\xampp\htdocs\sphinx\vendors\questasy.conf
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats the sphinx config file , but do have you definitly setup the 'plugin' with the right settings? You have search listening on p9312 - is that where the client is expecting it?

Comment: Yes defenetly. Here a little thing from the log:`[Mon Feb  9 11:48:10.615 2015] [ 6828] listening on all interfaces, port=9312
[Mon Feb  9 11:48:10.624 2015] [ 6828] listening on all interfaces, port=9306`

Comment: Thats the 'server' component. But is the 'client' using the same settings, ie looking for searchd in the right place?

Comment: im not how to check what u mean? There is a service running listening to this port and the config says that querrys are send to this port, but it doesn't work. I'm a little bit confused. ^^